# Spring Integration TCP Inbound Adapter client disconnect issue

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

We have created an IntegrationFlow for an inbound TCP server. Whenever we test this the integration is fine until the client disconnects, then we get a continuous flow of empty messages.

Spring Integration 5.2.5.RELEASE

Flow:

```java
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow inboundFlow(MyService myService) {
   return IntegrationFlows.from(
       Tcp.inboundAdapter(
           Tcp.netServer(12345)
               .deserializer(TcpCodecs.lengthHeader4())))
       .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
       .log(INFO) // Logging only for testing 
       .handle(myService, "process") // Do some processing of the message
       .get();
}
```

Test method:

```java
public void sendPackets() throws Exception {
    List<Path> files = getAllFilesSorted("/some/location");
    try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 12345)) {
        log.info("local port: {}", socket.getLocalPort());
        try (OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Path path = files.get(i);
                log.info("{} ({} of {})", path.toString(), i, files.size());
                byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
                outputStream.write(bytes);
                outputStream.flush();
                Thread.sleep(200);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Partial Log after test completes:

```
2020-05-05 11:00:52.963  INFO 31793 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=, headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=59407, ip_connectionId=localhost:59407:44745:df23388b-b8b0-4250-b926-4199030b2ff6, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=813ccf6b-9eb7-2ff3-0f8d-f2810966d8d7, ip_hostname=localhost, timestamp=1588672852963}]
2020-05-05 11:00:52.963  INFO 31793 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=, headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=59407, ip_connectionId=localhost:59407:44745:df23388b-b8b0-4250-b926-4199030b2ff6, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=1fd5c4c7-b2e0-6a89-7de6-894c8e42e242, ip_hostname=localhost, timestamp=1588672852963}]
2020-05-05 11:00:52.963  INFO 31793 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=, headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=59407, ip_connectionId=localhost:59407:44745:df23388b-b8b0-4250-b926-4199030b2ff6, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=78b852e8-0094-f8b9-8d05-37bc4912d096, ip_hostname=localhost, timestamp=1588672852963}]
2020-05-05 11:00:52.963  INFO 31793 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=, headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=59407, ip_connectionId=localhost:59407:44745:df23388b-b8b0-4250-b926-4199030b2ff6, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=4e4a7ee0-c66e-9501-9ef7-4d25143531b3, ip_hostname=localhost, timestamp=1588672852963}]
2020-05-05 11:00:52.963  INFO 31793 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=, headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=59407, ip_connectionId=localhost:59407:44745:df23388b-b8b0-4250-b926-4199030b2ff6, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=c90abe17-7036-94cc-af59-3b0cac5e75e4, ip_hostname=localhost, timestamp=1588672852963}]
2020-05-05 11:00:52.963  INFO 31793 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=, headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=59407, ip_connectionId=localhost:59407:44745:df23388b-b8b0-4250-b926-4199030b2ff6, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=425d2e2a-75c5-0184-06da-6d27eb546931, ip_hostname=localhost, timestamp=1588672852963}]
2020-05-05 11:00:52.965  INFO 31793 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=, headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=59407, ip_connectionId=localhost:59407:44745:df23388b-b8b0-4250-b926-4199030b2ff6, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=4c55d1d0-7421-1832-23ca-03744419c847, ip_hostname=localhost, timestamp=1588672852965}]
2020-05-05 11:00:52.965  INFO 31793 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=, headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=59407, ip_connectionId=localhost:59407:44745:df23388b-b8b0-4250-b926-4199030b2ff6, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=05b6fea6-8f76-5c74-e4cc-33bd8099d8e8, ip_hostname=localhost, timestamp=1588672852965}]
2020-05-05 11:00:52.965  INFO 31793 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=, headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=59407, ip_connectionId=localhost:59407:44745:df23388b-b8b0-4250-b926-4199030b2ff6, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=9b8fe16c-07f4-b64b-faec-794eb743559c, ip_hostname=localhost, timestamp=1588672852965}]
2020-05-05 11:00:52.965  INFO 31793 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=, headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=59407, ip_connectionId=localhost:59407:44745:df23388b-b8b0-4250-b926-4199030b2ff6, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=222725e8-19c6-62b6-8ba7-103892191c96, ip_hostname=localhost, timestamp=1588672852965}]
2020-05-05 11:00:52.965  INFO 31793 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=, headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=59407, ip_connectionId=localhost:59407:44745:df23388b-b8b0-4250-b926-4199030b2ff6, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=951403b6-18a9-ffe9-29b7-67b8c01ea311, ip_hostname=localhost, timestamp=1588672852965}]
2020-05-05 11:00:52.965  INFO 31793 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=, headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=59407, ip_connectionId=localhost:59407:44745:df23388b-b8b0-4250-b926-4199030b2ff6, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=2ac3002b-ccd1-9506-f3aa-60f4b63e26b8, ip_hostname=localhost, timestamp=1588672852965}]
2020-05-05 11:00:52.965  INFO 31793 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=, headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=59407, ip_connectionId=localhost:59407:44745:df23388b-b8b0-4250-b926-4199030b2ff6, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=dbbf12cf-0a27-407b-0a96-5b27ab0539db, ip_hostname=localhost, timestamp=1588672852965}]
2020-05-05 11:00:52.965  INFO 31793 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=, headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=59407, ip_connectionId=localhost:59407:44745:df23388b-b8b0-4250-b926-4199030b2ff6, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=3282d09e-9508-b053-3763-cc23d3c817a8, ip_hostname=localhost, timestamp=1588672852965}]
2020-05-05 11:00:52.966  INFO 31793 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=, headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=59407, ip_connectionId=localhost:59407:44745:df23388b-b8b0-4250-b926-4199030b2ff6, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=549b2326-341f-19c0-db98-6b31da1901d8, ip_hostname=localhost, timestamp=1588672852966}]
```

Comment: I don't see how that's possible; enable DEBUG logging for `org.springframework.integration`. If that doesn't explain what's happening; post the log someplace (like pastebin) and comment here that you have done so. You should also edit the question to show what version of Spring Integration you are using.

Comment: @GaryRussell Uploaded log with DEBUG enabled to https://pastebin.com/Y6MRpyTb - you can see on line 137 the first empty message. I don't see anything around this that might indicate what is causing this.

Comment: `com.hawkeyeinnovations.tennis.scoringprovider.config.SmartDirectorTCPIT$TestClientConfig'; from source: 'bean method client'`. Looks like you have some `client` config for that test environment. Probably it connects to the same server...

Comment: @ArtemBilan Yes, I forgot to remove that client. Ran again with it removed and behaviour is the same. If I extract the test `sendPackets` method to it's own java app I get the same behaviour (been running in a `@SpringBootTest` for expediency)

Comment: OK. Any chances to share with us a simple Spring Boot project to let us to reproduce and play with?

Comment: There is nothing in the log about the client disconnecting. See my answer for a suggestion.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Created a simple project - https://github.com/marksilcox/SO61610809

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the log about the client disconnecting. We would see socket close activity in the log.

The log implies we are receiving packets containing `0x00000000`.

Use wireshark or similar to look at the activity on the wire.

**EDIT**

Your custom deserializer is causing the problem.

```java
        if (read < 0) {
            return 0;
        }
```

You need to throw a `SoftEndOfStreamException` when you detect a socket close.

This is explained in [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/ip.html#custom-serializers-and-deserializers).

> When the deserializer detects a closed input stream between messages, it must throw a `SoftEndOfStreamException`; this is a signal to the framework to indicate that the close was "normal". If the stream is closed while decoding a message, some other exception should be thrown instead.

Comment: Wireshark is not showing the packets containing `0x00000000`. After the last successful packet I see a FIN from the client socket connection and then another from the server to the client.

Comment: Strange; the FIN should result in a socket close and terminate the `pool-1-thread-2`.

Comment: Your example is using a custom deseerializer whereas your question has one of the standard ones. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: You should also call the `read()` method instead of `inputStream.read()` to get the header. There is a small (but non-zero) probability that you won't get all 4 bytes in a single read.